# Using angular directive causes error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, directive, circular-dependency

http://plnkr.co/edit/dBe36L6vwOZOykujFRfg

In the plunker, I'm getting the following angular error: "10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!"

The logic works when used in index.html:

```
<h1>(working) Fruit from main document: {{vm.randomFruit().name}}</h1>
```

But throws the error when I try to call similar code in the directive with an object passed in:

```
<h1>(causing error) Fruit from directive template: {{fruit.name}}</h1>
```

It also appears to not throw the error in the directive if I simply do this in the scope function:

```
//this works for both instances
return vm.fruits[0];
```

However when I touch $scope.fruits in any way, even just to copy it, it thows the error on the directive version.

```
//something about touching the array here exposes the error, even though it still works
var x = [];
angular.copy(vm.fruits, x);
return x[0];
```

Why is this error being thrown here? It appears to be some type of circular dependency, but why only on the directive version?

Is there a better way to use a directive, template, and passed-in parameter object that is more standard?

> Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting! Watchers fired in
>   the last 5 iterations: [["fn: parentValueWatch; newVal:
>   {\"name\":\"apple\"}; oldVal: {\"name\":\"apple\"}"],["fn:
>   parentValueWatch; newVal: {\"name\":\"apple\"}; oldVal:
>   {\"name\":\"apple\"}"],["fn: parentValueWatch; newVal:
>   {\"name\":\"apple\"}; oldVal: {\"name\":\"apple\"}"],["fn:
>   parentValueWatch; newVal: {\"name\":\"apple\"}; oldVal:
>   {\"name\":\"apple\"}"],["fn: parentValueWatch; newVal:
>   {\"name\":\"apple\"}; oldVal: {\"name\":\"apple\"}"]]
>       at Error (native)
>       at Object.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.js:7925:19)
>       at Object.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.js:8097:24)
>       at done (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.js:9111:20)
>       at completeRequest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.js:9274:7)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.js:9244:11)

---

### Update 1

Updated aFruit() to randomFruit() in order to better demonstrate my issue:

```
$scope.randomFruit = function() {
//something about touching the array here exposes the error, even though it still works
var x = [];
angular.copy($scope.fruits, x);
//do some custom stuff here, sorting, etc. <whatever>
var randomIndex = Math.floor((Math.random() * x.length));
return x[randomIndex];
};
```

---

### Update 2

Was told not to use $scope, so completely removed it from the controller. Still seeing the same error.

```
myApp.controller('FruitCtrl', function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.fruits = fruits;

  vm.randomFruit = function() {
    //something about touching the array here exposes the error, even though it still works
    var x = [];
    angular.copy(vm.fruits, x);
    //do some custom stuff here, sorting, etc. <whatever>
    var randomIndex = Math.floor((Math.random() * x.length));
    return x[randomIndex];
  };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the approach, how the data is passed to the Angular. Angular has awesome data binding and it checks if the model is changed and updates the UI. Once the UI is updated, it checks again for the next round of changes. If data is changed all the time, it can stuck in the loop.

In this particular case the Angular does not understand that the data is the same. It receives new array on every digest loop and assumes that the data is changed, updates UI and starts checking again.

Make sure that you are not updating arrays from the UI on every $digest loop or returning new array on every $digest loop.
e.g.
This will call infinite loop:

```
$scope.aFruit= function() {
  return [
  {"name":"apple"},
  {"name":"orange"},
  {"name":"banana"},
];
};
```

This will work properly, because the reference to the array, stays the same

```
var myFruits =   return [
      {"name":"apple"},
      {"name":"orange"},
      {"name":"banana"},
    ]    
$scope.aFruit= function() {
    myFruits;
    };
```

Comment: JanisP is correct, here's what I'm assuming you wanted it to do: http://plnkr.co/edit/cFchj9uxVZRj5Fe8L5Al?p=preview

Comment: Also I suggest you check out the new component method in Angular 1.5 which are much more concise directives.

http://plnkr.co/edit/7leRr2TfoVOSfdVjxNK0?p=preview

Comment: @hsiung - no, simply returning the first element is not what I'm meaning to do. It's a more complex function like returning a random element from the array or sorting the array and returning the top <x> value from it. I have updated the original question to better get my point across.

Comment: @Buchannon Update 1 is still the same thing - you are recreating and returning new array on every digest cycle. It causes infinite loop. Try not to use scope functions in the views, they are executed multiple times on screen rendering (try to throw break point in them to see, how they work)

Comment: @JanisP Update 2, I got rid of all $scope references and am still seeing the same issue. If I need a property to be dynamic (calculated) and also passed into a directive, it seems to throw this error.

Comment: please see if the answer I posted accomplishes what you are looking for

Comment: @Buchannon some comments around the code, to explain the issue http://plnkr.co/edit/qoD66BemzyheYNrbLW8R?p=preview

Comment: In your example the logic has been moved to the directive and you are passing in the entire array. May or may not be the desired solution.

Comment: @hsiung at least I didn't change it to string :)

Comment: whoa, not trying to put you down...just saying that maybe OP wants to keep the logic in the controller. And I don't see what's wrong with passing in the string, that's what he's using in the template. Obviously if there were more properties on the object and the entire object was needed then a different approach would be taken.

Answer (score -1):

Oh ok gotcha!
There are two ways of doing this but I believe you're looking for this approach.

http://plnkr.co/edit/E1y9nqh0DdaHGW2hi4AM?p=preview

The thing is you're method is returning an object, but you want to grab the string value. So we change the method to this:

```
$scope.randomFruit = function() {
  var x = [];
  angular.copy($scope.fruits, x);
  var randomIndex = Math.floor((Math.random() * x.length));
  return x[randomIndex].name;
};
```

Next, we need to change our component bindings to accept strings with '@'

```
bindings: { fruit: '@' },
```

Last, we need to invoke the method in our template and use interpolation to set it as the value we pass in to the component:

```
<show-fruit fruit={{randomFruit()}} />
```

Hope this helps, again there's another approach but if you want to invoke your method ***in*** the template this is how you would have to do it.

Comment: Nice try, but I'm wanting to pass in the entire object to the template, not just one of the properties. I know the template is only using the "name" property right now, but this is a very simplified example of what I'm trying to do with my code base in another project.

Comment: Ok, so if you're trying to pass in the entire object then you can't copy it. That is what Janis originally said. You're generating a new object on every digest cycle and therefore angular doesn't know when to stop.

- You can either pass the function in using '&' bindings and invoke the function inside the directive 

- invoke the function in the controller and assign the output to a scope variable and then pass that new object to the directive

- You can do what Janis did and put the logic in the directive


- Or you can operate on the original collection (ie. don't copy it)